# Can you paraphrase this part of this paragraph please?

Tags: meaning

What does it mean when it says reminders it held of foreign places?

The landscape Miss Cotell was unaware of, while she dreamed instantly forgotten dreams, faded into winter dusk. Miss Keble failed to interest herself in a newspaper someone had left behind and instead thought about the house they were returning to, and the rooms in which their two lives had become entangled over the years, for which furniture, piece by piece, had been chosen together, where childhood memories had been exchanged. Miss Keble, as she sometimes did when she was away from the house for longer than usual, **saw as if in a vision the reminders it held of foreign places where there’d been holidays:** the Costa del Sol; the beach at Rimini; Vernon, where they’d stayed when they visited Monet’s garden; and the unidentified setting where an obliging stranger had operated Miss Cotell’s Kodak, allowing them to pose together.

Comment: Miss Keble (as she sometimes did when she was away from the house for longer than usual) saw (as if in a vision) the reminders (in this case most likely photographs) it (the house) held of foreign places (photographs of foreign places) where (in those places) there had been holidays.

Comment: the punctuation is wrong: Miss Kebble [,,,]  saw, as if in a vision, the reminders it held of foreign places where **they’d been** on holidays [...] There is also that mistake in the verb. It= the house that holds reminders of past holidays.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Miss Keble is remembering some souvenirs that she keep in that house, reminders of her holidays.

**[souvenir](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/souvenir)**

> something you buy or keep to help you remember a holiday or special event

**[reminder](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reminder)**

> something that helps someone remember